# Character type gives an int — what is this int?

Tags: c

In a C program, I want to take an int type input but after I run the program, I will give a character type as input but it doesn't get any error and it shows an integer. Why?

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int x;

    printf("input: ");

    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("the output is %d",x);

    return 0;

}
```

After compilation:

```
input: a
the output is -1225407932
[Program finished]
```

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: @Md ART The variable x is not initialized and any garbage can be outputted.

Comment: You do get an error but you ignored it.  The `scanf()` function returns 0 indicating that it failed to convert any input into a number (but that there was data to process; it did not encounter EOF).  The character you typed is still in the input buffer, waiting to be processed by a subsequent I/O operation.

Answer (score 3):

You do get an error but you ignored it.

When you type `a` but [`scanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) is told to expect an integer, it returns 0 indicating that it failed to convert any input into a number (but that there was data to process; it did not encounter EOF).  The character you typed is still in the input buffer, waiting to be processed by a subsequent I/O operation.

The variable `x` that you passed to `scanf()` is still uninitialized after the call — it was not modified by `scanf()` because the conversion failed.  Technically, printing an uninitialized variable such as `x` invokes undefined behaviour, but in practice, you get some quasi-random value output.

Answer (score -1):

If you have initialized the variable you would have got the output as 0. It doesn't give an error because char is just a 8-bit integer which can fit int on into.